# Simple echo of array values

Tags: php, arrays

New to php, trying to learn about arrays.

What is wrong with the code below? I need to echo out the results in order to pass them to another page.

```
<?php 

$stmt = $conn -> prepare("
    SELECT 
        MONTHNAME(TimeStamp), COUNT(*)
    FROM
        transactions
    WHERE
        TimeStamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP);");

$stmt -> execute();

$stmt -> bind_result($month, $days);

while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
        $data[] = array(
        'month' => $month,
        'day' => $day);
    }

print_r($data);

$data = array();

foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['month'];
    echo $row['day'];
}

$stmt->close();

?>
```

When I `print_r($data)` I can see the array fine in the following format.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [month] => January [day] => 323537 ) [1] => Array ( [month] => February [day] => 217304 ) [2] => Array (...
```

Comment: You realize that you overwrite your array with an empty array: `$data = array();` ?!

Comment: In order to pass it in another page you must use `header("Location:your_path_to_the_second_page/.$your_variables");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r($data);
**$data = array();**

foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['month'];
    echo $row['day'];
}
```

You print_r your $data, then you set it to an empty array with $data = array(), and in the foreach you are trying to go through an empty array.

Solution:

```
print_r($data);

foreach($data as $row) {
    echo $row['month'];
    echo $row['day'];
}

$data = array();
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining!